# auto scroll uipickerview when button is clicked

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am using a UIPickerView to display answers to a question. There needs to then be a button to reveal the correct answer if the user cannot work it out. I have tried the below, but the app crashes. How can i autoscroll to the correct answer?

```
-(void)reveal {

    [myPickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];

}
```

**EDIT: Yes i am just trying to get it to scroll to the first answer in the above example :)**

[ExcerciseController reveal:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68398f0
2012-10-30 14:57:21.673 English[20786:f803] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[ExcerciseController reveal:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x68398f0'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x1397022 0x108ccd6 0x1398cbd 0x12fded0 0x12fdcb2 0x1398e99 0x1f214e 0x1f20e6 0x298ade 0x298fa7 0x298266 0x2173c0 0x2175e6 0x1fddc4 0x1f1634 0x21a3ef5 0x136b195 0x12cfff2 0x12ce8da 0x12cdd84 0x12cdc9b 0x21a27d8 0x21a288a 0x1ef626 0x2c5d 0x2b85)
terminate called throwing an exception[Switching to process 20786 thread 0xf803]

Comment: Its difficult to guess at this time of the day!

Comment: The code you've posted is the answer. In this case, if the picker is scrolled to something other and the first object when you call this code, it will scroll to the top.

Comment: please check the function name.. you called reveal ?

Comment: share your code using http://pastebin.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`myPickerView` may not be the instance of `UIPickerView` as `UIPickerView` responds to selector - `(void)selectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component animated:(BOOL)animated`

Or you have to check how the method `reveal` is invoked.

Comment: hazzar!! you led to the right answer. i was invoking with reveal: instead of reveal

Answer (score 1):

Now, that the error/crash message is visible, it turns out that the error is not in how you call the picker's method. It is how you invoke `reveal`.

You call reveal with some object. Or you call it by passing a selector. However, the current selector that you are calling is `reveal:` but the methods name is `reveal` without any parameter. `reveal:` would require one parameter.

Wherever you call it, make sure that you call `reveal` and not `reveal:`

I assume you set the selector either in interface builder or when creating the button programmatically. That is the place where you made the mistake.

Some background:
The error message tells you what you need to know. A method name is called selector in Objective-C at runtime. In some literature you will find the wording of a message (named `reveal:` in your case) is sent to a receiver named `ExcerciseController` in your case.

Objective-C is polymorph. That means that `reveal` (called without any parameters) refers to another method implementation than `reveal:` (called with one parameter) or even `reveal::` (called with three parameters).

Answer (score 0):

please try to post the crash description,Need more blocks of code to answer it :)

However just try the below code

```
myPickerView.delegate = self;
[myPickerView reloadAllComponents];
[myPickerView selectRow:0 inComponent:0 animated:YES];
```